# Dropbox still "initializing" and won't sync

Tags: mac, sync, dropbox

I'm using OS X 10.5.8 and have been using Dropbox without any issues. However, for some reason it has suddenly stopped working.  I've tried the following:

1. Ran disk utility/repair permissions
2. Unlinked/re-linked my computer
3. Trashed setting folders, restarted app
4. Uninstalled/re-installed
5. Of course, I rebooted... a few times.

Nothing seems to overcome the problem. Can anyone direct me?

Comment: Did the network or your firewall change for any reason?
For example, if you are not at home, it might be because of some new proxy access policy (they can block ports for examples), or because your new firewall is much more restrictive than your previous one.

Comment: No firewall changes made by me... All seems to be running OK with newest version now.  Thanks a million for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my previous comment :

You can set your firewall settings according to the [Dropbox recommended procedure](https://www.dropbox.com/help/23).

For the proxy (unless you are sure you don't have one -if you're on your own network for example-), you can check this [Dropbox official help page](https://www.dropbox.com/help/21).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just noticed you're on OS X, for the corresponding help, there's a Mac icon on the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version from here:
http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=20472

Comment: Thanks Baztoune and Shiki. I'm on LAN, but it's just home network. I tried both settings, auto-detect and no proxy server... but no luck.  Loaded newest version, v0.8.64... and seemed to get hung up on "updating db." So... I did another disk utility/repair... rebooted, unlinked the computer from Dropbox, re-linked in new version... finally, it's working.  Don't know if it was the disk repair or the new software, but either way, I'm happy girl again... and very happy to have selective syncing!  Thank you, thank you, thank you.